# Script PHP que para um serviço no sistema operacional

Tags: php, sistema-operacional, centos

alguém sabe se existe algum comando no php ou script que pare um serviço no sistema operacional ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `exec`, e executar um `killall -9 [nome_do_processo]`

```
<?php
    exec("killall -9 mysql"); // mysql, por exemplo
<?
```

Comment: hmm legal vou tentar aqui Obrigado !

Comment: Rafael, eu consigo por exemplo no lugar do killall -9 colocar outros comandos, como por exemplo parar o apache pelo CentOs, exec("sudo service httpd stop");  ??

Comment: O exec serve exatamente para você executar comandos como se tivesse em um terminal. Então, fique a vontade. Pensando agora, só não sei como o script irá lidar com permissão, a não ser que você rode o script PHP com sudo.

Comment: Legal Rafael, vou dar uma olhada aqui, de qualquer forma obrigado cara ..

Comment: =) boa sorte! De nada!